# Before unload event - jQuery AJAX cross-browser issues?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser, onbeforeunload

I am developing some super-basic website tracking software. A small snippet of code embedded in client sites loads a javascript file from a CDN which tracks visitor actions on the client site - clicks, time on page etc.

When they navigate away from the page it triggers the `beforeunload` event to send the collected data via `jQuery` `AJAX` to a `PHP` processing file hosted on my server.

I am aware there are cross-browser issues with `beforeUnload`. I thought I got around these issues by following this article: http://jonathonhill.net/2011-03-04/catching-the-javascript-beforeunload-event-the-cross-browser-way/

It works probably 90% of the time. But sometimes if I check my php error_log I can see that the event is firing, but I am getting no data from the AJAX request.

I don't know how to debug this if it is an AJAX issue - the requests are being sent from the client sites. Or perhaps this is an issue with `beforeUnload`.

Just to clarify it a bit more here's my snippet of code where I send the data with `jQuery AJAX`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    jQuery.ajax('http://www.example.com', {
        async: false,
        data: 'tracking_data='+JSON.stringify(data),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache:false
    });
};
```

Any ideas? I've been stuck on this for a month now!

Comment: I've found firephp a pretty good resource for helping to debug ajax/php issues. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @whoopah, I'll check it out for sure. But if the AJAX requests are originating from remote clients sites, triggered by visitors to those sites, I won't be able too see any of this in a debug console will I?

Comment: firephp will work on the php processing page on your server so if I understand correctly you should be able to see the data that it is trying to process.

Comment: Yea I can see that in my error_log. And it's getting nothing. So I assume my AJAX request if failing. But there's no way to tell.